# Getting the value of a JQueryInstance

Tags: jquery, smalltalk, seaside

I'm still trying to get to understand how Javascript is wrapped in Seaside, say I have the following query:

```
(html jQuery: '#myId') hasClass: 'myClass'
```

How do I get a true or a false out of this? For example in my case I'd love to be able to do:

```
html anchor
   onClick: 
      (((html jQuery: '#myId') 
          hasClass: 'myClass') 
              ifTrue: [doSomething]
              ifFalse: [doSomethingElse]);
   with: 'Magic Stuff!'
```

What's the seaside way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends where you want to perform the decision on the client or on the server?

**Decide and Perform Action on Client**

You can use

```
((html jQuery: '#myId') hasClass: 'myClass') 
   then: aTrueExpression
   else: aFalseExpression
```

where `aTrueExpression' and`aFalseExpression' are other (jQuery) JavaScript expressions.

**Decide and Perform Action on Server**

You serialize the result of your expression into an AJAX callback and perform the action on the Smalltalk side:

```
html jQuery ajax
   callback: [ :value |
       value = 'true'
           ifTrue: [ " true block " ]
           ifFalse: [ " false block " ] ]
   value: ((html jQuery: '#myId') hasClass: 'myClass')
```